# MySQL JOIN, GROUP BY, ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table of products:

```
CREATE TABLE products (`id` INT);
```

And a table of images for those products:

```
CREATE TABLE images (`id` INT, `product_id` INT, `default` TINYINT(1));
```

I need to select all the products, and join the images table so that images with (`default` = 1) will be preferred, and if a product has no images with (`default` = 1), an image with (`default` = 0) will be shown in its place.

---

Here's an image showing what I'm looking for:

[image]

---

Right now I have this query:

```
SELECT p.id, i.id
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, url
    FROM images
    ORDER BY default
) AS i
ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.name
```

Which doesn't prioritize "default" images. The subquery doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was just missing a 'DESC' in the subquery's ORDER BY

:\

Answer (score 2):

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d948/1)

```
select products.id,
       coalesce(t1.mid,t2.mid) as image_id      

from products
left join (select min(id) mid,product_id 
                  from images where `default`=1
                  group by product_id ) t1
        on products.id=t1.product_id
left join (select min(id) mid,product_id 
                  from images where `default`=0
                  group by product_id ) t2
        on products.id=t2.product_id
```

Comment: This query is very slow. I optimized it as such: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d948/6/0 But in my tests it's still slower than my query when any columns other than the product_id and image_id are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one image for product, then try this query -

```
SELECT p.*, i.* FROM products p
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY `default` DESC) i
    ON p.id = i.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  p.id productid, 
  IFNULL(i1.id, i2.id)
FROM products    AS p
LEFT JOIN images AS i1  ON p.id = i1.product_id
                       AND i1.`Default` = 1  
LEFT JOIN images AS i2  ON p.id = i2.product_id
                       AND i2.`Default` = 0
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient than my query?

Comment: @kryo It always depends. But I thing yours will be better since it involved only one JOIN.

Comment: Looks like with my 13 'sample' products and 19 'sample' images they're about the same.

Guess we're deciding after it goes live... :D