# MySQL - JOIN, GROUP BY with ORDER of grouping

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Person {
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
}
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Address {
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Person INT NOT NULL,
    Street VARCHAR(50),
    HouseNumber VARCHAR(15),
    City VARCHAR(75),
    Zipcode VARCHAR(10),
    CountryCode CHAR(2),
    IsPrimary TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
}
```

Each person can have muptiple addresses, but at most one can be primary (`IsPrimary = 1`).

I want to get list of persons with one address. If person has primary address, it should be provided, if not, it does not matter, which address is retrieved.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    p.Name,
    p.Surname,
    a.Street,
    a.Housenumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode
FROM
    Person AS p        
LEFT JOIN (select * from Address ORDER BY IsPrimary DESC) AS a ON p.ID = a.ID_Person
GROUP BY p.ID
```

but that does not provide results that I expect. I expected first row of joined table to be retrieved when performing `GROUP BY`, but that is not the case.

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079799/mysql-join-group-by-order-by) but the solution is rather difficult in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` in a sub query usually only slows down you query.
You will have to order the result instead:

```
SELECT
    p.Name,
    p.Surname,
    a.Street,
    a.Housenumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode
FROM
    Person AS p        
LEFT JOIN Address AS a ON p.ID = a.ID_Person
GROUP BY p.ID ORDER BY a.isPrimary
```

This query has a second problem: It is not ANSI compliant, so it only works in MySQL when MySQL is not running ANSI compliant.

Assume this:
You have 1 `p.ID` with two rows in the table `Address`. There are no `GROUP` functions applied to `Address.City`, how does the database know which `City` to display? It does not, so you see a random one. To prevent this apply functions to all columns which are not in the group by (or place the columns in the group by).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, this is best done as a ranking query.

```
WITH PersonAddress AS (
  SELECT 
    p.Name,
    p.Surname,
    a.Street,
    a.Housenumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY a.IsPrimary DESC) AS rn
  FROM Person AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Address AS a ON p.ID = a.ID_Person
)
SELECT * FROM PersonAddress WHERE rn = 1;
```

Before MySQL 8.0, windowing functions are not available. The workaround is to use session variables:

```
SELECT 
  t.Name,
  t.Surname,
  t.Street,
  t.Housenumber,
  t.City,
  t.Zipcode
FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.Name,
    p.Surname,
    a.Street,
    a.Housenumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode,
    IF(p.ID = @pid, @rn:=@rn+1, @rn:=1) AS rn,
    @pid := p.ID
  FROM (SELECT @pid:=0, @rn:=1) AS _init
  CROSS JOIN Person AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Address AS a ON p.ID = a.ID_Person
  ORDER BY p.ID, a.IsPrimary DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```